# Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in App.config?

Tags: c#, json

I am using the WPF application, Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in app.config? If not, what is the maximum length I can set?

Comment: What's the Property Type ? Integer ? Long ?

Comment: A web.config for your WPF application?

Comment: need app.config for wpf application

Answer (score 2):

The MaxJsonLength cannot be unlimited, is an integer property that defaults to 102400. Set property on your web.config:

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

It is an integer so the max value you can set is: **2147483644**

Comment: I have a project that does not have a web.config, only app.config, is there a similar node to add for that or will this one just transfer straight over?

Comment: did you try that? @WWZee